# firebug - Hide styles from specific .css file

Tags: css, firebug

Is there any way that I can hide styles from specific stylesheets in firebug style panel?
For example I use CSS reset and include `reset.css` in my pages but it does not look good when it displays useless information in style window.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to make that clear - you want to hide the reset rules from firebug, but still apply them to the page: you don't want to remove the css reset file?

Answer (score 11):

I know you are asking about disabling stylesheets with FireBug.  You asked two years ago.  People suggested to hack FireBug and to use another web dev plugin.

Here's my solution:
The new Firefox (13.0.1) can do this without a plugin.  Just go to web developer tools section of the options and got to style editor (shift F7).
Options>web developer tools > style editor

Click on the eyeball to show/hide each stylesheet.

hope this helps!

Comment: OP wanted the styles hidden in Inspector but still applied to the page. Disabling a file in Style Editor disables its styles as well. Not a solution then.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have it already, consider installing this [Webdeveloper Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/)

It can do exactly what you ask for.. And a lot more :)

Comment: Yes it works, but as mentioned @Kobi, I want still apply them to the page

Answer (score 3):

There is no user interface to do this so far (Firebug 1.9.2), but you can modify the source code...  Which mean, however, that you'll need to do this each time Firebug is updated.

First, quit Firefox and find the .xpi package for Firebug.

> On my XP machine, it's located in "C:\Documents and Settings\ ***userName*** \Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ ***profileName*** \extensions"

Open the file "**firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi**" (it's actually a renamed .zip file) and extract the file "**content\firebug\lib\url.js**".

In this file, find the "**Url.isSystemURL**" function and add a line of code to return true if the **url** parameter contains the name of the CSS file you want to hide (I've used "reset.css" in the example below) :

```
Url.isSystemURL = function(url)
{
    if (!url) return true;
    if (url.length == 0) return true;
    /*** Hide specific CSS file ***/
    if (url.indexOf("reset.css") != -1) return true;
    /******************************/
    if (url[0] == "h") return false;
    if (url.substr(0, 9) == "resource:")
        return true;
    else if (url.substr(0, 16) == "chrome://firebug")
    ...
```

You can also use a regular expression :

```
    if (url.match(/RegExp/)) return true;
```

When you're done editing, save the file and replace the one in the .xpi with your edited version.

Comment: It might not be a pretty solution, but I think this is the only response that actually answers the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Heres how you do it [image]

Comment: downvote because you included no solution and no links in this answer

Comment: The picture is worth thousand words, if you dont understand, nobody can help it :( You cant simply downvote because of that.

Comment: +1, this worked for me but I had to figure out that I have to install Developer Tools first for Firefox. It will be better if you mentioned that to improve your answers in the future

Comment: Nice answer, but I wouldn't vote up because it lacks some info, such as Ahmad says. Community should support newbies and newcomers so what you, nespotin, said about 1k words is not correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/web-developer/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) you can install the Web Developer extension.

There's an option to disable CSS styles: CSS meny > Disable Styles > All styles (or individual styles you choose).