# A quick way to disable CSS in Firefox 18 or 19

Tags: firefox

Anyone know a quick way to disable CSS in Firefox 18 or 19? And the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: You have a couple of options for Firefox in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255606/firebug-disable-specific-css-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable CSS in Browser for testing purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046738/how-to-disable-css-in-browser-for-testing-purposes)